# iptables string match for spam not working

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I am trying to get iptables to string match on the email subject line that we've identified as spam. Its a Cent 6.8 box with iptables v1.4.7. For example the email subject line as its seen in WireShark is:

```
Brand-New Supplement That Even Hollywood Stars Rumouring About
```

I'm doing a hex string match with the hex data from the packet

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587 -m string --hex-string "|42 72 61 6e 64 2d 4e 65 77 20 53 75 70 70 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74 20 54 68 61 74 20 45 76 65 6e 20 48 6f 6c 6c 79 77 6f 6f 64 20 53 74 61 72 73 20 52 75 6d 6f 75 72 69 6e 67 20 41 62 6f 75 74|" --algo bm --to 65535 --icase -j DROP
```

However this is not working. Its the very first rule in the INPUT chain. I have done this before successfully with UDP 53 subdomian attacks, but that was using a single keyword. Is there something I'm not taking into account with long strings that include spaces? I've tried both hex and regular string match. I've also tried running the hex together in the rule with no spaces. All no luck.

Comment: Are these mails delivered via STARTTLS? If so, iptables has no visibility into the text. Even if they're not encrypted on the wire, the emails may be MIME messages, with parts uuencoded, in which case your match won't work either.

Comment: Some are STLS via 587, but we have seen just as many on 25 with no encryption. But I do see references to MIME in the packet payload.

Comment: Can you actually see the text you're looking for in a packet capture?

Comment: Yes, the text in is the pcap

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m string --hex-string "|0D|communication|08|loginpro|03|com" --icase --from 40 --to 66 --algo bm -j DROP. That is an iptables string I used to prevent a DNS lookup. Perhaps it will help you. IIRC I used -j LOG to establish whether or not it was matching.